# How would I order my collection on timestamp and score

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with documents that have a createdAt timestamp and a score number. I sort all the documents on score for our leaderboard. But now I want to also have the daily best.

matchResults.orderBy("score").where("createdAt", ">", yesterday).startAt(someValue).limit(10);

But I found that there are limitations when using different fields.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations.

So how could I get the results of today in chuncks of 10 sorted on score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple orderBy(...) clauses to order on multiple fields, but this won't exactly meet your needs since you must first order by timestamp and only second by score.

A brute force option would be to fetch all the scores for the given day and truncate the list locally. But that of course won't work well if there are thousands of scores to load.

One simple answer would be to use a datestamp instead of timestamp:

```
matchResults.where("dayCreated", "=", "YYYY-MM-DD").orderBy("score").startAt(...).limit(10)
```

A second simple answer would be to run a Cloud Function on write events and maintain a daily top scores table separate from your scores data. If the results are frequently viewed, this would ultimately prove more economical and scalable as you would only need to record a small subset (say the top 100) by day, and can simply query that table ordering by score.

Scoreboards are extremely difficult at scale, so don't underestimate the complexity of handling every edge case. Start small and practical, focus on aggregating your results during writes and keep reads small and simple. Limit scope by listing only a top percentage for your "top scores" records and skip complex pagination schemas where possible.

Comment: Isn't `.where("dayCreated", "=", "YYYY-MM-DD").orderBy("score")` still using multiple fields?

Comment: You can use multiple `orderBy` and multiple `where` calls. That's not the problem here. What is a problem is if you use a range query (e.g. `<` or `>`) and then your first `orderBy` is not the same field.  So by using `=` on the day instead of a range (which matches your goal to get the days top scores) you can orderBy on an alternate field.